# Java write to file using multi-threading doesn't speedup execution

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl

I have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520805/java-threads-in-opengl-application) some time ago to get an idea of speeding up image writing to file.I basically have an OpenGL app.At the end of each render loop I save the frame buffer into image file.

```
   fbo.readFrame();

   glReadPixels(0, 0, _viewportWidth, _viewportHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _data);
   _data.rewind(); //ByteBuffer
   new TImageExporter(ImageExporter.TGA, "renderings/", _data, _viewportWidth, _viewportHeight, true, _frameCount++).run();
```

The TImageExporter extends Thread and inside the "run()" method I execute writing to File.
To my surprise The render loop for 50 frames takes almost the same time as if I use a single thread version of the Image Exporter. (3293 milliseconds -multi-threaded and 3437 milliseconds using single threaded).What do I do wrong here? 
That is the code inside TImageExporter:

```
public void export() {
    _pixels = new int[_width * _height];
    int bindex;
    int plenght = _pixels.length;
    // convert RGB data in ByteBuffer to integer array
    for (int i = 0; i < plenght; ++i) {
        bindex = i * 4;  //use 3 for RGB
          //// here write the pixels to RGBA/////
         ............
         .......................

    }

    _image.flush();
    _image.setRGB(0, 0, _width, _height, _pixels, 0, _width);
    _image = ImageUtils.flipY(_image);

    renderByFormatType();

}

private void renderByFormatType() {


    String formattedString = String.format(_formatString, _frameCount);

    if (_exportType.equals(TGA)) {
        try {
           writeTGA(_image, new File(_renderPath + "screenshot_test" + formattedString + ".tga"), _flipX);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TImageExporter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }




}

@Override
public void run() {


        export();



}
```

UPDATE:
People have asked here if I write to the same file.No, each thread writes to a completely new file.

UPDATE1:
Set a global static variable that holds array of BufferedImage.Now each new TImageExporter
writes the image data to that array to a different index.All I got is 3038 milliseconds instead of 3437 when writing directly to Disk.

Comment: do you copy that _data ByteBuffer before passing it to the thread?

Comment: also, have you run your code through a profiler to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: @jtahlborn ,yes I duplicate it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-threading will not speed up file transfer because:

> 1. making a non-thread safe file write will overwrite some of the information the other threads are writing when 1 thread goes to save
>      it.
> 2. Disk I/O is your bottle neck.  The best thing to do it write what you want to into a memorystream (someone edit and give documentation i
>      can't find it real quick) and allow it to write to the disk.. this
>      will allow constant disk i/o without worrying about threads

Comment: So you say it is better for me to write it into ByteBuffers and at the end of rendering save those to files.And if I have like 10000 frames to write? Can it blow up the memory ?Can I have a static or global array to hold the BufferedImage instances which are created in each thread inside TImageWriter?

Comment: yes it can blow up the memory.. Remember your constraints an Int is 4 bytes, a char is 2 bytes.  The more you can write to the disk at one time the better.  If you want, make a program that generates a random int, and saves it to a file. Keep a count and see how many times it does it in a minute.  Then generate 1000 ints (4K worth of memory) and save those to the file for 1 minute and you'll be surprised how much better your disk I/O is

Answer (score 2):

Even though your code is multi threaded ; since all you Threads are trying to access the same file..it wont make much difference..because in this scenario even though lot of threads are running; at one instant all except 1 will be waiting to acquire write access to file.

Comment: They don't access the same file.Each one writes into new file."_frameCount++" takes care of it .

Comment: @MichaelIV They still use the same disk.. Disk I/O is your enemy here. The more files you try to write to, the more down time going from file to file writing to the disk.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you think it will be faster? The disk isn't multithreaded.

Comment: this makes no since at all... threads don't even exist when it comes to physical drives.

Comment: @MattWestlake Exactly my point. Multiple threads in the CPU doesn't extend as far as the disk, so why would they do the I/O any faster. The multiple threads are sequentialized at the disk, if not before. There is no point to them.